# validating FCKeditor

Tags: javascript, fckeditor

how can FCKeditor be validated for required field using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
var EditorInstance = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('message') ; 
if(EditorInstance.EditorDocument.body.innerText.length<=0)
{
alert("This firld is mandatory");
EditorInstance.EditorDocument.body.focus();
return false;
}
```

**Source:**

http://dreamtechworld.wordpress.com/2008/12/06/validating-firld-in-fckeditor-using-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Use FireBug, and see what hidden `textarea` it is updating. Then check that element.

```
if (document.getElementById('fckinstance').innerHTML === '') {
    alert('required field');
}
```

That is just an example. It probably doesn't use an `id` like that either, because of multiple instances on the same page.

The `textarea` that FCKeditor replaces is probably the one that holds its HTML.

Note too, the FCKeditor can *seem* blank, even though there is HTML in it.

Answer (score 1):

To Validate FCKeditor for being empty, create below function and call it whenever going to validate your editor containing TEXTAREA:

```
function FCKCopy() {
    for (var i = 0; i < parent.frames.length; ++i ) {
        if (parent.frames[i].FCK)
            parent.frames[i].FCK.UpdateLinkedField();
    }
}
```

Then add another function to Strip HTML tags from TEXTAREA's value:

```
function stripHTML(oldString) {
    var matchTag = /<(?:.|\s)*?>/g;
    return $.trim(oldString.replace(matchTag, ""));
}
```

In above function used jQuery's trim function. Use jQuery or replace it with some trimming function for java script such as:

```
function trimIt(text) {
    rwhite = /\s/;

    trimLeft = /^\s+/;
    trimRight = /\s+$/;

    if ( !rwhite.test( "\xA0" ) ) {
        trimLeft = /^[\s\xA0]+/;
        trimRight = /[\s\xA0]+$/;
    }

    return text.toString().replace( trimLeft, "" ).replace( trimRight, "" );
}
```

Now you can check value of TEXTAREA for example as below:

```
if (stripHTML($('message').val()) == '') {
     alert('Please enter Message.');
}
```

Hope it will work as good as worked for me.

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

this may be useful for someone

```
var EditorInstance = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('JobShortDescription');

alert(EditorInstance.GetHTML());
```

resource is http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/JavaScript_API